# Python sys.argv to preserve ' ' or ""

Tags: python, sys

terminal:

```
python test.py blah='blah'
```

in test.py

```
print sys.argv
['test.py', 'blah=blah'] <------------
```

How can blah arg preserve its '' OR
Is there a way to know if an arg is wrap with either "" or ''?

Comment: That's not something Python controls.. That is your *shell* removing the quotes before passing it on to Python.

Comment: It’s the shell that ‘strips’ the quotes; use `python test.py "blah='blah'"` instead.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). Why do you want the quotes?

Comment: If you need your application to accept free-form text instead of the  symbolic-ish data from command line arguments, it'll likely be easier to read it from stdin.

Comment: please mention the OS or the shell you are using

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your *shell* removes the quotes before invoking Python. This is not something Python can control.

Add more quotes:

```
python test.py "blah='blah'"
```

which can also be placed anywhere in the argument:

```
python test.py blah="'blah'"
```

or you could use backslash escapes:

```
python test.py blah=\'blah\'
```

to preserve them. This does depend on the exact shell you are using to run the command.

Demo on `bash`:

```
$ cat test.py 
import sys
print sys.argv
$ python test.py blah='blah'
['test.py', 'blah=blah']
$ python test.py "blah='blah'"
['test.py', "blah='blah'"]
$ python test.py blah="'blah'"
['test.py', "blah='blah'"]
$ python test.py blah=\'blah\'
['test.py', "blah='blah'"]
```

Comment: is the behavior OS independent?

Comment: @hus787: Very much so. It depends on the shell implementation. On windows, the `cmd` console quoting uses different rules from the `bash` shell. I have little experience with `tsh` or `zsh` but they may well use different rules *again*.

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
python test.py blah="'blah'"
```