# How to call preserve quotes when passing arguments?

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I have a piece of code that looks like this. The real code is of course much longer. I have shortened it to condense it to the idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from sys import argv

class Base():
    def whoami(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

    def foo(self, a, b):
        print(a+b)

class A(Base):
    def bar(self, a):
        print(a)

class B(Base):
    def fizz(self, a, b):
        print(a+b)

def main():
    eval(argv[1] + '().' + argv[2] + '(' + ', '.join(argv[3:]) + ')')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Expected output:

```
$ ./myScript.py A whoami
A
$ ./myScript.py B fizz 5 7
12
$ ./myScript.py B fizz '5' '7'
57
```

But the actual output for the last line is:

```
$ ./myScript.py B fizz '5' '7'
12
```

The quotes does not get passed. My goal is to be able to call the various class methods easily from command line for debugging. I don't know if my approach is wrong from the beginning.

And yes, I'm aware of security risks with `eval`. I intend to remove it when the code goes into production.

Comment: The quotes are never preserved, since these are "directives" for the shell how to interpret the parameters. It is usually used to add spaces to the parameters, like `command 'foo bar' qux`, versus `command foo bar qux`

Comment: May be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19120324/6699447) will help.

Comment: You can however add quotes in your parameters, like `myscripty.py B fizz '"5"' '"7"'`.

Comment: Using `eval` like that would give a security engineer a heart attack and a penetration tester a field day

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's is a viable solution. You could post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

> The quotes does not get passed. My goal is to be able to call the various class methods easily from command line for debugging.

The quotes are *not* part of the parameters you used. The quotes are interpreted by the shell. Usually quotes are used to add spaces to a parameter.

For example:

```
command foo bar
```

will pass two parameters (`foo` and `bar`) to the `command`, but if you want to add spaces, you can use:

```
command 'foo bar'
```

Now the shell will interpret this as a single parameter, with a space.

You can however add quotes in your parameters, like:

```
command '"foo"' '"bar"'
```

or:

```
command "'foo'" "'bar'"
```

to pass values with quotes (double quotes `"` in the first example and single quotes `'` in the second one) to the command. You can escape parts of the parameters as well, like `command "\"Thank you\", she said."`, and thus use double quotes and single quotes in the same parameter.

That being said, please do *not* use `eval(..)` to evaluate strings. `eval(..)` has severe security risks, see [*Security of Python's `eval()` on untrusted strings?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661084/67579) for more information. You can use [**`ast.literal_eval`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate literals. Furthermore you can use a dictionary, etc. to route the call to the correct function(s).

Comment: Nice answer. I'll wait a few days with accepting it in case something better comes up. I have upvoted it.

Comment: How could anything better come up? This is the truth, in terms of how the shell parses command strings into argument vectors.