# Parsing arguments in argparse into other arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I define an argument parser in a Python script (`script.py`) as follows:

```
import arparse
import sys


# define the parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", type=int)
parser.add_argument("-b", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-c", type=str)

# and parse the arguments from sys.argv or a list
parser.parse(sys.argv[1:])
```

If I call my program like this (call 1):

```
python script.py -c "-a 1"
```

`sys.argv[1:]` looks like `["-c", "-a 1"]`. That's what I expected so far. Here, I want the resulting namespace to be:

```
Namespace(a=0, b=False, s=['-a 1'])
```

But `argparse` reads the second list element not as argument of `-c` but as individual argument and raises an error, because `-s` expects one argument. I had a deep look into argparse, because so far I thought this is a bug in argparse. So, I locally "fixed" argparse to detect `"-a 1"` as argument of `-c` and not as `-a` argument. (Basically, I told argparse that there's a difference between `"-a 1"` and `"-a=1"`.)

But then I realized, that this does not help when calling my script by (call 2):

```
python script.py -c "-b"
```

as my trick doesn't work any more (there's no potential `=` to not be detected). Here my expectation is to get:

```
Namespace(a=0, b=False, s=['-b'])
```

but argparse again reads the `"-b"` as new argument and complains that `-s` got no argument. And here I cannot trick argparse because it needs to be able to distinguish between call 2 and this (call 3):

```
python script.py -c -b
```

But for both calls 2 and 3, `sys.argv[1:]` looks like `["-c", "-b"]`.

Then, I thought it might be a bug in the `sys` library and the calls 2 and 3 should end up in two different arrays, i.e. `["-c", "\"-b\""]` and `["-c", "-b"]` but this might break many other applications that rely on the current implementation of `sys`.

For my specific case, I found a hack to make argparse parse my stuff the way I want it to get parsed by modifying `sys.argv[1:]` before passing it to the parser. But in general, I don't know how to solve the problem/inconsistency or if one just has to accept it.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120247/python-sys-argv-to-preserve-or

Comment: `Namespace(a=0, b=False, s=['-b'])` ??    did you mean `c` and not `s` ?

Comment: The first parse_args` should return `Namespace(a=None, b=False, c='-a 1')`. Use ' -b' (with leading space) if you don't want it to be a '0b' flag string.  `argparse` strongly prefers to treat a dashed string as an `optionals` flag.

Comment: On further thought, that '-a 1' might be treated as a '-a' flag.  I'd have to test it.  In any case, arguments starting with a dash can a be problem for argparse.  Try to avoid them.

Comment: @slothrop: I didn't use a specific shell. AFAIK, it's read into `sys.argv` the same in every shell.
@hpaulj: For the problem where I encountered that, I fixed it similarly. But it cannot be a solution to avoid this.

Comment: @RomanJoeres The shell does have an influence, because it may remove the quotes before invoking the Python process. There's nothing that any code in `sys` or anywhere else in Python can do to counteract that. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19120324/765091. When you say "I didn't use a specific shell": you must be running the command *somewhere*, right? Even if that's your OS's default shell, it's still a shell that will have rules for how it processes quotes.

Comment: Btw, in your question, "call 2" and "call 3" are identical: both are `python script.py -c "-b"`. Do you intend for them to be different?

Comment: @RomanJoeres, distinguishing between `-c -b` and `-c "-b"` is impossible. _Always_ impossible. There is no distinction to make; they're 100%-identical command lines -- use `strace -e execve sh -c './yourcommand -c -b'` and compare it to `strace -e execve sh -c './yourcommand -c "-b"'`. You need to define `-c` to **always** take an argvar so whatever is after it is parsed literally.

Comment: @slothrop: Thanks for the clarification about shells, I didn't know that. In every shell, I've worked with, the behavior was the same. 

The concrete bug, I experienced in PowerShell, the Ubuntu terminal of a WSL, and the terminal of Rocky Linux: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_Linux.

I updated call 3 again. I guess, it was changed when it was edited at some point. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I'd argue that this is a duplicate of [argparse: leading dash in argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636309/python-argparse-leading-dash-in-argument); or, better, [can't get argparse to read quoted string with dashes in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it)

Comment: ...following those, one gets a link to the upstream CPython ticket: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/53580

Comment: (...alas, the result of reading those references is not encouraging; the bottom line is that argparse is broken-by-design, and will not be fixed).